# I'm trying to open a PowerPoint file from SharePoint , I receive the following error: method of object failed run-tim error 2147467259 (80004005)

Tags: vba, sharepoint, powerpoint

The code is intended to copy the source PPT which is automatically created to a different template. This works if the file is on a local C: drive but if I move it to SharePoint, this doesn't work.

```
Sub CopySlidesBetweenPresentations()

    Dim sourcePPT As Presentation
    Dim destPPT As Presentation
    Dim sourceURL As String
    Dim destURL As String
    Dim sourceSlide As Slide
    Dim i As Integer
        
    'Be sure so specific UNC path for presentations for the specific client
    'Open both Presentations
    sourcePPT = "https://sharepoint.com/teams/layouts/15/guestaccess.aspx?share=ETjM2lSj4-hEp7aKGueqcuEBtgPWB_sVZfzdHAOTWJ8dQQ&e=OYlHaX"
    destURL = "https://sharepoint.com/teams/layouts/15/guestaccess.aspx?share=EfNfyDt77a9LlAQlNJO2ODkB3L3WA17rYvM9GjquY3JRoQ&e=s32f0D"
    Set sourcePPT = Presentations.Open(sourceURL)
    Set destPPT = Presentations.Open(destURL)
        
        'Copy the content
        sourcePPT.Slides.Range.Copy
        Set destPPT = ActivePresentation
        ActivePresentation.Slides.Paste
        
        
        For i = 1 To 3 'remove first 3 slide copied over from the source Presenation
            destPPT.Slides.Item(i).Delete
        Next i
                          
    ' Save changes to the new presentation
    sourcePPT.Save
    sourcePPT.Close
    
    ' Close the source presentation without saving changes
    destPPT.Close
    
End Sub
```

I initially used the URL in quotes in the `Presentations.Open` method but that didn't work so I went to using a variable and assigned the URL to it but no success. I verified that I'm authenticated to that SharePoint library and tested it by pasting the link into a browser.

Comment: Which line has the error?

Comment: Set sourcePPT = Presentations.Open(sourceURL)

Comment: There's most likely a problem with the URL you're using.  Try opening the file in PowerPoint directly from SharePoint, then go to File >> Info and click the "Copy Path" button.  Paste that copied path into your VBA.

Comment: If your SharePoint paths are really long then that could be a problem...

Comment: I made the change and received an error that the URL cannot exceed 255 characters in length....progress although still not working. I then moved the file to a different SharePoint location now the file opens in SharePoint in a browser but still receive this error: Run-time error -2147467259 (80004055) Method 'Open' of object 'Presentations' Failed.

Comment: Working OK for me  - eg `Presentations.Open("https://contoso.sharepoint.com/sites/ABC/TestLibrary/Presentation.pptx")`   I don't have much else to add on top of what I already suggested.